# python 2d array list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

```
j=0
i=0
text=[[0 for x in range(5)]for y in range(2)]
while (i<5):
    for link in soup.findAll('td'):
        if j<2:
            text[i][j]=link.string
            j+=1
i+=1
```

The problem is I get the error message `list index out of range` but I already set the if condition so if `j` exceed `3` will nth happen. So what is the problem?

Comment: you get your `i` and `j` indices mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(2)]
```

creates the array `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Your code is built for an array which looks like: `[[0, 0], [0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0]]`.

So either `i` and `j` are around the wrong way or your:

```
[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(2)]
```

isn't giving you what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
text=[[0 for x in range(5)]for y in range(2)]
```

is equal to

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So inside your list, you have 2 lists with 5 elements each one.

Then look at this line:

```
text[i][j]=link.string
```

`i` - is number of elements in variable `text` (you have 2)

`j` - is number of elements in each list (you have 5 elements)

It looks like you have mixed `i` and `j`.